# Calling a method in a modal initially hidden (transition)

Tags: vue.js

I have a simple method "updateTotal" initialized in my app / vue :

```
// start app
new Vue({
el: '#app2',
data: {
    showModal1: false,
    showModal2: false,
    total : 0
},
methods: {
    updateTotal: function (num) {
      this.total = this.total + num
    }
}
})
```

When I call this method from by example a button in the HTML code in the app2 section, it's OK (text "total" updated).

When I call this method from a div section hidden at the loading of the page (it's a modal, with vue.js "transition" system), I have this error :
Property or method "updateTotal" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

The code of this modal / transition (it's IN the app2 div) is :

```
<!-- template for the modal component SERVICES-->
                <script type="text/x-template" id="modal2-template">
                <transition name="modal2">
                    <div class="modal-mask">
                    <div class="modal-wrapper">
                        <div class="modal-container">

                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <slot name="header">
                            Header
                            </slot>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body">

                                <!-- LISTE SERVICES -->
                                <div>
                                    <div>

                                        <div class="control">
                                        <label class="radio">
                                            <input type="radio" name="service1" v-on:click="updateTotal(10)">
                                            Oui
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="radio">
                                            <input type="radio" name="service1" checked v-on:click="updateTotal(-10)">
                                            Non
                                        </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>


                                        <div class="control">
                                        <label class="radio">
                                            <input type="radio" name="service2" v-on:click="updateTotal(20)">
                                            Oui
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="radio">
                                            <input type="radio" name="service2" checked v-on:click="updateTotal(-20)">
                                            Non
                                        </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- LISTE SERVICES -->

                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <slot name="footer">
                            default footer
                            <button class="modal-default-button" @click="$emit('close')">
                                OK
                            </button>
                            </slot>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </transition>
                </script>
```

What can I do to be able to call this method from this modal / transition div ?

Thanks !

MAMP MySQL PHP5

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs since you try to call `updateTotal()` from within the template of a different component.

The context within the `template` is always the component itself (`this`). Since the method `updateTotal()` is not defined in this component, you cannot call it.

There are several workarounds, but I consider two the cleanest:

1. For simple projects/apps: emit an event  that triggers the method in the parent (like your `close` event)
2. For more complex apps: Use shared state with Vuex and make your method an `action`